# Why should I explicitly cast my JASON object as a Map<String, dynamic> in Dart?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

If the dart convert package returns a json object, is there any advantage or necessity to casting the converted json to a Map<String, dynamic>? In the code below, I'm taking the response from an api and passing it to a factory that returns a Dart Place object. I'm trying to understand the benefit of casting the json as a map versus passing the result as a json object. Thanks for any insights.

```
var parsedJason = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
var resultObj = parsedJason['result'] as Map<String, dynamic>; 
return Place.fromJson(resultObj);
```

Comment: `jsonDecode` returns a `dynamic` type and not a `Map<String, dynamic>` because the returned object also could be a `List`.  You usually should check first (or prepare for a possible `TypeError` if your cast fails).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know, the JSON result for REST API gets outputted as a Map of key: value pairs where the key is always a String and the value can be of any type i.e. dynamic in Dart.

Casting the result as Map<String, dynamic> makes sure that the resultObj variable passed as a parameter in the fromJson() method is of the correct type accepted by the method, thus making the query error prone.

Comment: Except of course, when it's a `List<dynamic>` and not a map at all.

Comment: You said, "thus making the query error prone."  Did you mean "less error prone" since the method is actually expecting a Map<String, dynamic>? Sorry for not mentioning that in the original question.